# Is my proof of the weakening principle correct?

Tags: logic, proof-verification

Could you please check if my proof of the weakening principle of intuitionsitic logic is correct?

$$\Gamma \vdash B \Rightarrow \Gamma, A \vdash B$$

> **Proof:** Let $\Gamma \vdash B$. Hence there is a derivation $\frac{D}{B}$ with undischarged assumptions in $\Gamma$ and with conclusion $B$. But then, there must be a new derivation $\frac{\frac{A}{D}}{B}$ with undischarged assumptions in $\Gamma \cup \{A\}$ and conclusion $B$, that is to say, $\Gamma, A \vdash B$.

Is really this simple or I am missing something?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could say that it is even simpler.

$\Gamma \vdash B$ is usually defined as meaning that there is a proof from premisses in $\Gamma$ to $B$.

But since anything in $\Gamma$ is in $\Gamma \cup \{A\}$, if there is a proof from premisses in $\Gamma$ to $B$, then trivially there is a proof from premisses in $\Gamma \cup \{A\}$ to $B$

So trivially if $\Gamma \vdash B$, then $\Gamma \cup \{A\} \vdash B$